# What are advantages of MQTT over TCP/IP? Since MQTT is based on TCP, Why don't we use TCP/IP instead of it?

Tags: tcp, mqtt

I am studding the MQTT & TCP/IP protocol.

Since i'm able to know that, MQTT is based on the TCP so as the TCP/IP 
& we refer MQTT though we have the TCP/IP Protocol.

Why don't we use TCP/IP instead of MQTT?

Is there any advantages of MQTT that makes it better solution than the TCP/IP protocol?

Which is more reliable & required less no of data packet to form a communication?

**(Note : TCP/IP in the sense forming a network between 2 devices using normal TCP/IP protocol as in GSM modems "connect > transfer data > disconnect")**

Comment: Well, HTTP is based on TCP as well, and you wouldn't ask us to _use TCP/IP insttead of HTTP_, would you?

Comment: you maybe should go deeper on 'ISO layers'  study. TCP is at network level and mqtt application layer. So Mqtt rely on tcp to work. With an application layer protocol you can build your business logic and sending message without having the knowledge of network things..

Comment: With MQTT the sender knows whether the message was received.

Comment: @boly38 : I am more interested in the Protocol used in the GSM network to transfer a data over IP. In that manner we have many types of protocols (TCP/UDP/HTTP/ICMP/MQTT etc). I want to know what will be the effect when we try to form a TCP/IP network communication & same using MQTT protocol. please refer the link (page no 2, Software Features->Protocols) [link](https://www.quectel.com/UploadFile/Product/Quectel_EC25_LTE_Specification_V1.8.pdf) Here they mentioned TCP & MQTT. Even we will found different protocols it in stack (SDK). so my question is what is difference between them?

Comment: You cannot directly compare protocols at different levels in the OSI network model. @user207421 there is no end to end delivery notification in MQTT.

Comment: GSM provides the layer below IP, TCP is a layer on top of IP, MQTT is a layer on top of TCP. Please go and research the OSI network model

Comment: @hardillb I didn't say received by whom. I carefully avoided saying anything about end to end. But you do know it has been received by the broker, and the broker knows whether it has been received down the line, and so on until delivery. TCP gives you none of that. All you know is that the connection hasn't failed visibly yet.

Comment: @user207421 Feels strange to compare protocols on different layers but in my eyes, TCP gives you that confirmation. As you probably know, TCP (segment) works with Sequence Numbers and Acknowledgement numbers to ensure error correction and flow control. If the SEQ number does not match the expected ACK number the sender will notice that and resend the segment. This way (from an upper layer perspective) the sender can be (almost) certain that the receiver successfully received the data after the FIN/ACK is exchanged and the TCP connection gets closed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there any advantages of MQTT that makes it better solution than the TCP/IP protocol?

Yes, it offers things TCP doesn't offer, namely an application layer protocol. Other examples of such protocols are FTP, HTTP, SMTP.

You're asking the wrong question. IP makes sure you can send data to another machine, TCP makes sure this data is received in-order and acknowledged, and application-level protocols make sure you can make sense of the data you receive.

Without an application level protocol, you have no meaningful communication. Where each sockets programming example begins with "WriteLine" and "ReadLine" text message exchanges, that in itself is (albeit a very rudimentary) application level protocol, namely "client and server exchange text messages ending in a newline".

So, no, you cannot use TCP/IP without an application level protocol, because as soon as you start writing a program sending and/or receiving data, you have at that moment defined an application level protocol.

With its own problems. And that's why you shouldn't invent your own protocol, but use existing ones. Pick the one that suits your needs. Do you need to publish or subscribe messages to some broker, use MQTT.

Unless you know very well what you're doing, don't invent your own.

Answer (score -1):

The benefits of using MQTT over TCP/IP far outweighs the data overhead it introduces. Also, MQTT was devised to solve a specific problem of getting sensor data from a remote system which could not be connected to the consumer of the sensor data all the time.